# Error invalid_grant when trying to serialize items with Sitecore cli

Tags: scs

I'm working on dockerized Sitecore 10.3 solution with JSS and SXA but when I run the below command to serialize my items from Sitecore I get the error invalid_grant.

command

```
dotnet sitecore ser pull
```

Error
[image]

This was working nicely and stopped working suddenly.

Comment: The reason it stopped working is because when you initially up your containers with the up PowerShell script, it logs in. That login times out after a while, so you will need to log the CLI in again as in your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to login into your Sitecore instance by running the following command from your project root folder.

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority "https://your.id.host" --cm "https://your.cm.host" --allow-write true
```

Flags explanation

**--auth, --authority** Identity authority for the environment, i.e. identity server or AAD tenant URL

**--cm** Sitecore content management hostname to connect to

**--allow-write** Enables writing data to the environment